# how use autoplot + autolayer with a xts object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, xts

I'm trying use the `autolayer` function from `autoplot` in order to distinguish the forecasting and the testing part in a picture, but I'm working with a xts object. I use the window function to divide both set of data, but when I use the `autolayer` function from `autoplot`, I got the following error:

> Error: Objects of type xts/zoo not supported by autolayer

The question is: Is it possible to draw a similar graph with xts object using other method? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Seriet.xts_train <- window(Seriet.xts, 
                           start = as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                           end = as.Date("2017-12-31"))
Seriet.xts_train

-2015-01-01 03:00:00 1125
-2015-01-01 04:00:00 1086
-2015-01-01 05:00:00  978
-2015-01-01 06:00:00  947
-2015-01-01 07:00:00 1020
-2015-01-01 08:00:00 1303
-2015-01-01 09:00:00 1557

Seriet.xts_test <- window(Seriet.xts, start = as.Date("2018-01-01"))

Seriet.xts_test

-2018-01-01 03:00:00   55
-2018-01-01 04:00:00   30
-2018-01-01 05:00:00    9
-2018-01-01 06:00:00   13
-2018-01-01 07:00:00   19
-2018-01-01 08:00:00   49
-2018-01-01 09:00:00   43


st.fc.snaive <- snaive(Seriet.xts_train, h=24)

autoplot(st.fc.naive) + autolayer(Seriet.xts_test, series="Conjunto de validación")
```

> **Error: Objects of type xts/zoo not supported by autolayer.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distinguish train and test by coloring the train points black and test points red, say, then:

```
col <- rep(1:2, c(nrow(train), nrow(test)))
autoplot(rbind(train, test)) + geom_point(col = col)
```

or maybe just this:

```
autoplot(cbind(train, test), facet = NULL)
```

Comment: thank you for your appreciation, but the question is combine the forecasting from snaive algorithm and at the same time comparing this prediction with the real data from a xts object (the test data). for this purpose the clasical method is using autoplot + autolayer, but the problem is that autolayer function is not compatible with xts object. Then in this situation is not possible use cbind method. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 **autolayer** functions in R, one in the package *ggplot2* and other in the *forecast* package .

The error could be that you are using the one in the package *ggplot2*.

If you specify the origin correctly, it may work, only replaced:
*autolayer* by  **forecast::autolayer**

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very bright solution but, maybe changing type of xts object ts object at last stage would be a solution.

```
autoplot(ts(a_xts,start=c(2019,4,16),frequency = 
365.25))+autolayer(ts(b_xts,start=c(2019,4,16),frequency = 365.25))
```